# Como comparar os valores de um intervalo com outro, seguindo uma fórmula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho minha tabela de classificação de campeonato, que possui uma linha "*Número de Voltas por corrida*" e, abaixo,  "*Voltas Completadas*".

Quero percorrer todos os valores da linha "*Voltas Completadas*" e comparar com a "*Número de voltas por corrida*", com a seguinte lógica:

```
se Voltas Completadas < (Voltas por corrida*0,35 ), 
    retorna 1(quantas vezes ocorrer) na célula, 
senão, 
    retorna 0
```

Mas não consigo fazer funcionar. Tentei com `CONT.SE`, mas parece que só funciona com algum valor específico!

Como elaborar essa fórmula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a fórmula SOMA com a fórmula SE, utilizando o recurso de vetor.

No caso, para contar a quantidade de linhas que atendem o critério "O número de voltas completas deve ser menor que 35% do número de voltas por corrida", usamos a função SE comparando um intervalo de células com outro intervalo.

[image: Exemplo de aplicação da soma de vetor com critério.]

Após digitar a fórmula, tecle <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> para usar como **fórmula de matriz**.

Passo a passo, o Excel vai resolver esta função da seguinte forma:

1. A2:A5 = {3,2,1,0}
2. B2:B5 = {5,2,10,3}
3. B2:B5*0,35 = {5,2,10,3} * 0,35 = {1.75, 0.7, 3.5, 1.05}
4. A2:A5 < B2:B5*0,35 = {3,2,1,0} < {1.75, 0.7, 3.5, 1.05} = {3 < 1.75, 2 < 0.7, 1 < 3.5, 0 < 1.05}.
5. Colocamos para retornar 1 quando Verdadeiro e 0 para Falso. Assim:

   - {3 < 1.75, 2 < 0.7, 1 < 3.5, 0 < 1.05} = {0, 0, 1, 1}
6. No final, você terá `=SOMA({0, 0, 1, 1})`, que resultará em `2`.

Para saber mais:

- https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Diretrizes-e-exemplos-de-f%C3%B3rmulas-de-matriz-3be0c791-3f89-4644-a062-8e6e9ecee523

Comment: Obrigado @ricidleiv , funcionou!

Answer (score 0):

Bruno, se entendi, eu faria o seguinte:

Em uma célula usaria o CONT.SE para saber o total de voltas completadas, e compararia este valor com o número de voltas. É isso?

```
=CONT.SE(A1:Z1;">0")   para valores numéricos nas células (pode ser qualquer valor maior que zero)
```

Comment: Sim, é isto que quero fazer, já tenho a linha que computa as voltas completadas e também a de totais. Só não consigo usar a lógica dentro do cont.se...

Comment: Alterei o CONT.SE acima pois estava pegando uma coluna, seu caso é em linhas, no exemplo que fiz, ele entende quantos valores "numéricos" existem nestas células (de A até Z) que sejam maiores do que zero Veja se está colocando números como texto (p.ex.: "1") retire as aspas se for o caso, ou use o CONT.SE para textos, neste caso, sugiro que padronize o texto, p.ex: cada célula de uma volta recebe a letra "V", e onde está "<0" na fórmula, coloque "V".

Comment: Sim, nomeei as linhas também. O meu problema é que os valores são variáveis, pista a pista. Se fosse um único, estaria de boa, mas preciso verificar todas as ocorrências...

Comment: Se você colocar uma parte do que tem na plamilha para que possamos ver, fica mais fácil ajudar, dá para você "editar" sua pergunta e inserir além de textos, também imagens